# how to generate first n permutations then pause and restart?

Tags: python, loops, iterator, permutation, delimiter

Simple question i have the code from [how to skim itertools permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66684229/how-to-skim-itertools-permutations):

```
from itertools import permutations
ListX=["A","B","C","(",")","#"]
perm_iterator = list(permutations(ListX))
print(list(perm_iterator))
```

how do i pause, resume,stop, restart the iterations?

how do i see the iterations in steps of 100?

in steps of n?

Comment: What do you mean pause/resume? You can take as many items as you want by calling `next(iterator)` in a loop. See also [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an infinitely looping copy of an iterator then take chunks of `n` from it using `cycle` and `islice` from `itertools`.

```
import itertools

n_chunks = 30
chunk_size = 100
l = ["A","B","C","(",")","#"]

perm_iterator = itertools.permutations(l)
loop_perms = itertools.cycle(perm_iterator)
for n in range(n_chunks):
    print(list(itertools.islice(loop_perms, chunk_size)))
```